# Raspberry Pi: "Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP" error

Tags: raspberry-pi

*<sup>[Cross-posted to Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1914111)</sup>*

I have a Raspberry Pi 1B with Raspbian Buster and Wolfram Engine 12.0.1.

If I try to use J/Link, I get the following error message:

```
~ $ wolfram
Mathematica 12.0.1 Kernel for Linux ARM (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Needs["JLink`"]                                                                                                           

In[2]:= InstallJava[]                                                                                                             
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP

InstallJava::fail: A link to the Java runtime could not be established.

Out[2]= $Failed

In[3]:=
```

I am not using J/Link directly, but several components of Mathematica require it.

**Has anyone encountered this problem, and is there a solution?**

I have seen something similar when installing `wolfram-engine`. This could be solved by installing an older Java: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=212040 This question is not about installing `wolfram-engine` (which I managed to do) but about using it on a Raspberry Pi 1B.

I have the following versions of Java installed:

```
~ $ apt list --installed|grep jdk

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

openjdk-11-jdk-headless/stable,now 11.0.6+10-1~deb10u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jdk/stable,now 11.0.6+10-1~deb10u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jre-headless/stable,now 11.0.6+10-1~deb10u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jre/stable,now 11.0.6+10-1~deb10u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jre-headless/stable,now 8u212-b01-1+rpi1 armhf [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jre/stable,now 8u212-b01-1+rpi1 armhf [installed]
```

Trying to remove the `-11` ones with `apt remove` would also remove `wolfram-engine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually install `opendjk-8`:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Then, after having installed `wolfram-engine` (which will also install opendjk-11 and make it the default), manually choose openjdk-8 as the default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will show a list of choices. Choose openjdk-8.